# Polygon to raster. Empty raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, polygon, ascii

I am using ArcMap.

I am trying to convert polygon to raster and specify cell size to 6, but created raster is empty. If I leave the default cell size (0.0015) everything works. Last week I was doing the same thing on the same data and everything was working.

What can be wrong?

Later I need to convert this raster (clipped with another one) to ASCII. I've tried to resample raster which I had created previously (cell size 16). Works good, but then have to change the projection and cell size is automatically changed. After projecting raster I can't resample it again to 6 (error with too small or too big cell size appears). Even, if I leave the raster with unchanged cell size I can't convert it to ASCII (the process stays at 0%).

Answer (score 2):

What projections are you using? If your original cell size is 0.0015 it could be the projection has degrees as units, in that case a value of 6 is very high. 
It might be a better option to change the projection of the polygons first and only then convert it to a raster as this leaves less data loss. That the cell size changes when you change the projection can be normal, especially if different units are used.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to specify my cell size to 6 by first defining projection of my polygons, and then projecting it to another projection. Beginners mistake.